# Redmine: check if the user has a specific privilege

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Trying to write a plug-in for which I need to check if the user has a particular permission .
For example 
I am thinking of something like this

```
if (user.current has "view_private_notes" ) 
do something
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check User model. There is near exact you want:

```
  # Return true if the user is allowed to do the specified action on a specific context
  # Action can be:
  # * a parameter-like Hash (eg. :controller => 'projects', :action => 'edit')
  # * a permission Symbol (eg. :edit_project)
  # Context can be:
  # * a project : returns true if user is allowed to do the specified action on this project
  # * an array of projects : returns true if user is allowed on every project
  # * nil with options[:global] set : check if user has at least one role allowed for this action,
  #   or falls back to Non Member / Anonymous permissions depending if the user is logged
  def allowed_to?(action, context, options={}, &block)
```

You can extend existing models by your plugin and add methods you like combining existing:

//init.rb

```
 ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
  unless User.included_modules.include?(MyPlugin::UserPatch)
    User.send(:include, MyPlugin::UserPatch)
  end
 end
```

//user_patch.rb Something like this:

```
 def self.included(base)
   base.class_eval do
     unloadable

   # need to pass context to be able trigger allowed_to method in old way.
   has_right_view_project(project,context)
     self.allowed_to?({:controller => context[:controller], :action => context[:action]}, project, :global => true)
   end
 end
```

Actually it's easy to use existing methods.

Answer (score 3):

```
if User.current.allowed_to?(:view_private_notes, @project)
  puts "i know what you did!"
end
```